# How to stub child class using sinon

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, sinon

I have two classes, a parent class and a child of that.

```
class Api {
   constructor(stuff) {
      ...set stuff
   }

   doSomething() {
      ...doesSomething
   }
}
```

```
class UtilApi extends Api {
   constructor(stuff) {
      super(stuff);
   }

   getThings = async() => {
      this.doSomething();
      return things;
   }
}
```

I am used to stubbing in sinon using the syntax

```
sinon.stub(SomeClass.prototype, 'someMethod').resolves({});
```

However, when I try to do:

```
sinon.stub(UtilApi.prototype, 'getThings').resolves({});
```

I get the error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot stub non-existent property getThings
```

When looking into `UtilApi.prototype` in my test suite - I noticed its just the parent `Api`. So I can stub the method `doSomething` that's in the parent class, but I can't stub any method in the child class.

I have tried `callsFake`, `Ovject.setPrototypeOf` and `sinon.createStubInstance` - but all are not working.

How can I stub `UtilApi` to fake a return from the method `getThings()`?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to a commentor - I looked again at my code and I changed `getThings` from an arrow function to a regular function.

```
getThings = async() => {
      this.doSomething();
      return things;
   }
```

```
async getThings() {
      this.doSomething();
      return things;
   }
```

This solved the issue and stub correctly - will update when I know why it does not work with arrow functions.

**UPDATE 2**

Issue answered here https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/1136

Comment: I can't reproduce this...your code successfully stubs the method for me.

Comment: Hey @MarkMeyer, thanks for responding quick, it actually solved my issue - As you said it worked for you - I knew it had to be something wrong with my code. I looked again and getThings was actually an arrow function `getThings = async () => {}` - when I changed this into a regular function - it works as expected - no idea why - some reading to do on my side